# Ansible: loops with inventory groups elements

Tags: ansible

I got a bit stuck in the following problem. I have an inventory file similar with:

```
[server]
server0              ansible_host=10.254.1.35     
server1              ansible_host=10.254.1.46  

[worker]
worker0              ansible_host=10.254.1.10
worker1              ansible_host=10.254.1.12      
worker2              ansible_host=10.254.1.13
```

and I want to make a role that tests the connectivity between all machines from two groups (server0 to all workers, server2 with all workers etc).
So something like:

```
- hosts: "{{ target | default('server') }}"
  tasks
  - name: Test connectivity
    shell: |
    ping {{ worker_machine_ip }}
    args:
        executable: /bin/bash
```

where the worker_machine_ip to be replaced with the IP of each worker from the inventory file. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [special variable `groups`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) to list all hosts in a specific group, then the other sepcial variable `hostvars` to get the IP of that other host you want to ping:

```yaml
- hosts: "{{ target | default('server') }}"
  
  tasks:
    - name: Test connectivity
      shell: ping -c 3 {{ hostvars[item].ansible_host }}
      loop: "{{ groups['worker'] }}"
      args:
          executable: /bin/bash
```